# HighCharts JS series not showing lines

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

im initializing top and bot charts on my InitializeCharts function that calls InitalizeTopPlot and InitializeBotPlot but rendering the cart with the newer version 11.3.0 instead of 11.x.x lines not showing , it shows onlypoints if i drag my mouse into it

InitializeCharts functions:
https://gist.github.com/lucalauria0/c2c67eb28e27d94c0c88b5e782ab1dbe

it show points but not lines

[image]

Comment: This is a large amount of code, you can simplify it and recreate it in an online demo.: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sun57geh/   
Since you wrote this code, you know it best and it will be easier for you to limit it to a minimum where the error still exists. Then it will be easier to help you.